# Excel Symbols in Calculation

Tags: excel, office365

[image: Excel Symbols]

Can you guys please let me know how do I get the symbols in excel shown in the image below. I checked the cells but its simple B1-A1 formula but not sure how to get symbols there. Also, how do I get symbol if there is no change (<>) in same format as in image?

Comment: Look into [conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-data-bars-color-scales-and-icon-sets-to-highlight-data-f118d0a6-5921-4e2e-905b-fe00f3378fb9)

Comment: Triangle symbols start at unichar(9650)

Answer (score 1):

From the Home ribbon, click Conditional Formatting > Icon sets. In the arrows are the second item in the first category (Directional). Once selected, if you go back into Conditional Formatting and select to edit the rule, you will have options where you can set at what point it is to display each icon (up arrow, down arrow, or yellow bar, which you could use to indicate no (or insufficient) change.

While it doesn't look exactly like your image in color, the icon is the same. Consider an extra conditional format that matches the color of your text, if desired.